# Why replyEmail.AddBusinessCard (contact) in Outlook Macro get Expect Object error?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have to make a macro in outlook that enable to respond an email with a template and in this template, attach a contact vcard (as attachment).

Here is the code:

```
Sub ResponderConAttachment()

    Dim origEmail As MailItem
    Dim replyEmail As MailItem
    Dim contact As ContactItem
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myContacts As Outlook.Items


    Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     
    Set myContacts = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items
    
    Set origEmail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set replyEmail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\diego\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\RespuestaContacto.oft")
    
    Set contact = myContacts.Item(15)
    
    replyEmail.AddBusinessCard (contact) - ***This line gives an error saying is expecting an object.***
    
    
    replyEmail.To = origEmail.To
    replyEmail.CC = origEmail.CC
    replyEmail.Subject = origEmail.Subject
    
    replyEmail.HTMLBody = replyEmail.HTMLBody & origEmail.Reply.HTMLBody
    replyEmail.Display

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks to me like `myContacts.Item(15)` doesn't exist. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Hello Ken, thanks for your help! I run with the debugger and the contact exists and the debugger brings all the contact information, so it looks like an object indeed.

Comment: The only other thing on that line that could cause the error are `replyEmaili` being nothing, or `AddBusinessCard` is failing for some reason. Stepping through with the debugger should let you figure out which is not set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation may indicate brackets.

Remove them

```
replyEmail.AddBusinessCard contact
```